# NSInvalidArgumentException when putting UITableViewDataSource in a generic class

Tags: uitableview, swift

I tried to encapsluate my tables data source into an own class called `ArrayDataSource` which looks like the following lines of code:

```
public class ArrayDataSource<T>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var items: [[T]]

    // ...

    public func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items[section].count
    }

    // ...

}
```

This complies quite fine and no complaints about missing implementations are made, but when using it like

```
self.tableViewDataSource = ArrayDataSource<Stop>(items: stopsInSections, cellReuseIdentifier: "StopCell", configureClosure: { view, stop in /* ... */ })
// yes, self.tableViewDataSource is a strong reference, since self.tableView.dataSource doesn't seem to be
self.tableView.dataSource = self.tableViewDataSource
```

But when I use it, my app crashes with the following debug output:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtC12WannWieWohin15ArrayDataSource00000000146B4108 tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146b4250'
```

Any ideas what I could have made wrong?

Comment: if you type in "`po 0x146b4250`" in your "`lldb`" command line within Xcode, is the object of your expected type "`ArrayDataSource`"?

Comment: No, it returns `374753056`. Whatever that means.

Comment: `po self.tableView.dataSource` seems to point nowhere, while `po self.tableViewDataSource` points to the `ArrayDataSource`. But set `self.tableView.dataSource` in the line before the `self.tableView.reload()` is called inside `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: @miho if you can upload a sample project I'm willing to check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing generics from class declaration, your code will work.
But this looks like a bug(of generics or `respondsToSelector:`?).

```
// with Generics
public class ArrayDataSource<T>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource { ... }

var ds = ArrayDataSource<String>()
ds.respondsToSelector("tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:") // false

// without Generics
public class ArrayDataSource2: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource { ... }

var ds2 = ArrayDataSource2()
ds2.respondsToSelector("tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:") // true
```

Comment: Thank you for that lines of code. That's a pity, but at least I created a radar for it ([`radar://19343048`](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5829206453780480)).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use a generic swift class with Cocoa - the dynamic method calls fail.

One approach you can do at the moment is have a property on your generic datasource that returns a non-generic class that wraps your generic one.

There is an implementation of this approach here:
https://github.com/jonnermut/thesarvo/blob/master/thesarvo_iphone_2.0/thesarvo/thesarvo/Model/SectionedDataSource.swift